# Variables categóricas en PCA

Tags: estadística

Para hacer una análisis de componentes principales, es necesario que los datos
a tratar sean numéricas. Si hay variables categóricas/factores se aconseja que se conviertan a números.

¿Cómo se convierten?

¿Se pasan a variables dummy 0-1?

O ¿cambio cada factor por un número, en plan verde=1, rojo=2, amarillo=3?

Con el paquete  FactoMineR puedes añadir v.categoricas al PCA y usarlas como variables suplementarias pero estas no influyen en el análisis, solo como ayuda a la interpretabilidad.

Comment: Según entiendo un PCA asume que cada variable esta en una misma escala, lo cual  claramente es una dificultad con variables categóricas.  Eventualmente, podés tener factores ordenados  en los que puedas asumir una escala, por ejemplo malo-regular-bueno, tal vez pueda llevarse a -1, 0, 1 o 1, 2, 3, dónde cada categoría es 1 orden de magnitud mayor de la anterior. Esto es fácil de de hacer con un simple `as.numeric()` del factor, pero siempre, si las categorías están en orden. Otro caso, es el ejemplo que das : verde/rojo/amarillo, claramente no podemos decir "que rojo es es el doble que verde"

Comment: En estos casos, el procedimiento de variables dummy es más adecuado, deberías entonces manejar, tantas variables dummy (0-1) como categorías tengas. Por otro lado, por lo que leí, hay alternativas al PCA para variables categoricas, tal vez es cuestión de investigar un poco. si no tienes problemas con el inglés, hay buenas discusiones en https://stats.stackexchange.com/ Por cierto, así como está tu pregunta, me temo que está basada en opiniones, por lo que eventualmente terminará cerrada. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! No sabia que el procedimiento a seguir fueran "opiniones" .Pensaba que había una metodología a seguir en estos casos. Aquí algunas opiniones. Se ve que es un tema común. https://kpvlbwvqvp5urh545p5bteg67a--stats-stackexchange-com.translate.goog/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont

Comment: Lo  que yo entiendo al menos, es que la respuesta sería "depende", por eso las respuestas serían más bien opiniones, y además el otro problema, es que es una pregunta más de estadística que de programación, de hecho yo me mandé a darte un comentario pero soy apenas un programador, así que lo que te dije, deberías "tomarlo con pinzas".